# Convert a java class or jar to a dll that can be loaded in php as an extension

Tags: java, php, .net, dll

Is there a way to convert a java class or jar file to a php extension dll?

I know I can use iKvm to convert java to .net dll, but that dll does not load as an extension in php because php extension dll has some other format (or perhaps uses some other version of c/c++)

Comment: It's not possible. And it shouldn't be needed at all. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to write an extension for php in java, is that not possible?

Comment: No. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189160/writing-a-php-extension-in-something-other-than-c-or-c): *Q: "Is there a way to use something other than C to write a php extension?" A: "PHP extension is heavily dependent on C macros. Unless you have a year to spare to translate everything, C is pretty much the only option."*